# install apk from unity Luncher

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, path, apk

I am making a lucnher for my Android game, and I have created a script to download the game from the Internet, but after downloading I want to start installing the game on the phone directly without going to the game file, but there are some problems that I face first. This is the script that I use to start downloading the game.

```
void InstallAPK()
{
    string fileName = "Ball_Battle.apk";

    string apkFilePath =Path.Combine( Application.persistentDataPath , fileName);

    savePath_bool.isOn = false;

    string filePath = apkFilePath;
    AndroidJavaClass intentClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Intent");
    AndroidJavaObject intentObject = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_VIEW"));

    AndroidJavaObject file = new AndroidJavaObject("java.io.File", filePath);
    AndroidJavaObject uri = file.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("fromFile", file);

    AndroidJavaObject fileProvider = new AndroidJavaClass("androidx.core.content.FileProvider");
    AndroidJavaObject context = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer").GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

    uri = fileProvider.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getUriForFile", context, "com.Luncher.provider", file);

    intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setDataAndType", uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("addFlags", intentClass.GetStatic<int>("FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK"));
    intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("addFlags", intentClass.GetStatic<int>("FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION"));

    context.Call("startActivity", intentObject);

}
```

And this is the Mainfest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.Luncher.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@Android/file_paths" />
        </provider>

        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is the file path

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
</paths>
```

but when i build the Game on unity it give me these error
`WARNING:We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 34

This Android Gradle plugin (7.1.2) was tested up to compileSdk = 32`

`Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 AndroidManifest.xml:3:49-80 Error: Attribute application@icon value=(@mipmap/app_icon) from AndroidManifest.xml:3:49-80 is also present at [:unityLibrary] AndroidManifest.xml:31:9-43 value=(@mipmap/ic_launcher). Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:3:3-83 to override.`

`CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.`

I downloaded sdk 32, 34, 33, but the problem still exists. Is there a solution? Thank you.

Add file path but the unity give me error

Comment: The first part of your question has nothing to to with your second part. Also the first part about installing the APK has no actual question. Please decide what you want to ask, the APK installation or the gradle warning. On Stackoverflow you should only ask one question per question post.

Comment: apk installation

Comment: And what does not work about the APK install code?

Comment: Listen to me, my friend. I downloaded the apk file from the internet and put it in a file. After downloading, I want to install the apk on the phone automatically without the user going to the apk file and downloading it.

Comment: If I am not mistaken your `InstallAPK` method does exactly that: install an APK from file-system. Does this method work? Or are there any problems with this code besides the unrelated general gradle warning?

Comment: Yes, my friend, the apk is not installed. Do you have any solutions? Also, this script is specific to the phone, so I cannot know if there are errors or not.

Comment: I would recommend to edit your question and this very important detail. I would even mention it in the title. Have you checked logcat if it contains errors that could explain why installation fails?

Comment: make a new  sccript and make an exhiption and make an text = ex , and it give me error and i ask chat gpt about this error he told me that i want to use fileProvider and use a fileprovider but when build the game he give me Error build gradle